# Compile, Assemble and Disassemble Using the LLVM Tool Chain

Tags: llvm

I'm trying to run the following [example](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#examples) to Compile, Assemble and Disassemble an small program using the LLVM tool chain.

My intention is to learn how it works so in further tries I could do some performance test by changing and/or reordering the assmbly's instructions.

To start with, I first get the bite code of a dummy program:

```
    % llvm-gcc -O3 -emit-llvm hello.c -c -o hello.bc
```

Once I have the bite code, i try to use the llvm-dis utility to take a look at the LLVM assembly code and llc to compile the program back to native assembly using the LLC code generator (just for the shake of trying):

```
    % llvm-dis < hello.bc | less
    % llc hello.bc -o hello.s
```

But in both cases I get the following error:

```
    llvm-dis: Invalid MODULE_CODE_GLOBALVAR record
```

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

I've googled and I haven't found a solution. I have also tried to use

```
    otool -tV hello
```

But the output is not compatible with llvm. Instead of getting the following assembly format:

```
.section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
.globl  _main
.align  4, 0x90
    _main:
    Leh_func_begin1:
pushq   %rbp
    Ltmp0:
movq    %rsp, %rbp
    Ltmp1:
subq    $16, %rsp
    Ltmp2:
leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rax
```

I get:

```
__TEXT,__text) section
start:
0000000100000eb0    pushq   $0x00
0000000100000eb2    movq    %rsp,%rbp
0000000100000eb5    andq    $0xf0,%rsp
0000000100000eb9    movq    0x08(%rbp),%rdi
0000000100000ebd    leaq    0x10(%rbp),%rsi
0000000100000ec1    movl    %edi,%edx
0000000100000ec3    addl    $0x01,%edx
```

Which is not valid for me as I cat compile the latter assembly with for example:

```
    % gcc hello.s -o hello.native
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: llvm-gcc is deprecated. Can you try clang?

Comment: I have the similar problem. Have you solved it somehow???

Answer (score 5):

Make sure your llvm-gcc's version match the version of LLVM you installed - the binary IR format changes quite fast and is not backward compatible across several version.

Alternatively, you might try to emit *text* representation of LLVM IR out of llvm-gcc and assemble it through llvm-as.

Something like this:

```
llvm-gcc -emit-llvm -S foo.c -o foo.ll
llvm-as foo.ll -o foo.bc
llc foo.ll -o foo.S
```

etc.