# Installing Clang/LLVM/Ubuntu

Tags: linux, gcc, ubuntu, clang

I am required to use LLVM and Clang for a compilers class I am enrolled in.  This is not a question about the content of the class, just how to get the required software installed.

I am running gcc version 4.6.3 and have downloaded, built, tested, and updated what I believe to be LLVM suite version 3.4 (the latest svn edition).  I do a simple "hello world" application, as referenced on the LLVM getting started page, but on the line

```
lli helloworld.bc
```

I get the error "lli:helloworld.bc: Invalid MODULE_CODE_GLOBALVAR record"

Here are the instructions I ran in the terminal, most of which was taken directly from the LLVM website:

```
cd myFolder
svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk llvm
cd myFolder
cd llvm/tools
svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk clang
cd myFolder
cd llvm/projects
svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/compiler-rt/trunk compiler-rt
cd myFolder
mkdir build
cd build
../llvm/configure --enable-optimized CC=/usr/bin/clang CXX=/usr/bin/clang++
make
make check-all
make update
```

THEN

```
clang hello.c -o hello
clang -O3 -emit-llvm hello.c -c -o hello.bc
lli hello.bc
```

And that final line, lli hello.bc, is where I get the error above.

Here are my questions:

1. What is installed on my machine? How do I resolve this error?
2. My professor said we need clang and LLVM 3.3.  How can I get LLVM 3.3?

Comment: You should give more details about how you built LLVM (which is often packaged in most Linux distribution; you could simply `aptitude install clang llvm`). And you might ask that on LLVM mailing lists.

Comment: Could you edit the question to detail how, precisely, you generated the "helloworld.bc" file? Also, you might be interested in [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717868/compile-assemble-and-disassemble-using-the-llvm-tool-chain).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you typed:

```
clang -O3 -emit-llvm hello.c -c -o hello.bc
```

You used **the system's `clang` executable**, which is at `/usr/bin/clang`, and is not the clang you have just built. The two have a different version. `lli`, however, is the `lli` you've just built - Ubuntu doesn't come with it. That means you have generated a .bc file with an older LLVM version and then tried to run it with a newer LLVM version, hence the problem.

To verify this, you can check which `clang` you are using by typing `which clang` into the console.

The simplest way to remedy this is to type `./clang` (or any other path which isn't just the file name) instead of `clang`, which forces the shell to choose the file in the current directory.